# Best way to use reflection to call different methods of a class in a single utility method

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class with multiple methods which accepts different params and return different type like class `foo` in below example:-

```
class foo{
    public void A(int a , int b){
      // do somthing.
    }

    public String B(int a , String b){
        // do somthing.
        return "a";
    }

    public Object C(String a , String b){
        // do somthing.
        return null;
    }

    public int D(Long a , String b , String c){
        // do somthing.
        return 1;
    }
}
public class bar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class c = Class.forName("foo");
            Object t = c.newInstance();
            Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
            for(Method m : methods){
                String methodName = m.getName();
                if(methodName.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                    // How to call method with its argument and return the result using reflection.
                    m.invoke(t,);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }catch (InstantiationException e){

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // Handle any exceptions thrown by method to be invoked.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Now i want to create a utility method which accepts the method name and arguments and call the corresponding method using the reflection. Let me know how can i pass different method params using the generic utility method and return the result(it may return int,string,object as illustrated in the example) from the reflection code.

Comment: In general this is uncomputable. You can't possibly know what data value an arbitrary class is going to expect for each paramaeter of each of its methods.

Comment: @EJP is it possible if i pass a hashmap to the method, where key method name and value is the List of params and then using reflection i can  check the method name and get the argument list from the map and then invoke the method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code, the  `public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)` method of the Method class takes as second argument a varargs. So you can invoke the A(int, int) method in this way :

```
m.invoke(t, 3, 4);
```

But this will not solve really your problem.

> Let me know how can i pass different method params using the generic utility method and return the result(it may return int,string,object as illustrated in the example) from the reflection code.

It is a really poor design as you want to use reflection to do very specific things : call specific methods with specific arguments with a single entry point method.
It's error prone and slower.

For example you could have a method with 2 parameters in the entry point method :

- A string for method name
- varargs of Object for parameter values.

How use it ? 
Without type checking and by counting the position of each parameter passed in the declared method : very error prone.
Besides, if you add/remove or change a parameter in the used class, your reflective code will compile fine while at runtime it will raise a exception.

It seems really not a suitable case for reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation :).